# work with interface like java in C#

Tags: c#

We have such codes in Java

```
public interface SampleInterface{    
    public void Run();    
}

public void Action(SampleInterface param){
    param.Run();
}

public void someFunction(new SampleInterface(){
      void Run(){
           // the run functions works well
      }
})
```

but, that is not work in C#, please help me on passing interface as param in C#

My problem is here :

```
public void someFunction(new SampleInterface(){
    void Run(){
        // the run functions works well
    }
})
```

it seem that you can not define/new interface when passing interface

Comment: 1) You can't create a new interface because it is not a concrete type. 2) Your method parameters are type definitions for what can be passed in, you do not create the instances in the method signature (you do not do that in java either). Pick up a c# book and start at the beginning.

Comment: I have created a code simular to yours, please check if it works for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# does not support inline interface implementations like Java. What you want to achieve would be done using lambdas in C#

```
public void ActionRunner(Action param)
{
    param();
}
public void someFumction()
{
    ActionRunner(() =>
    {
        // Code goes here
    });
}
```

Of course implementing the interface in a separate class is also an option but I'm guessing you want something a bit more concise.

*Edit*:

The Action approach works if you have a single method, if you have multiple methods, and you need to often declare them inline, you could define a helper class, that implements the interface but can have the method implementations specified as `Action`/`Func` properties. For interfaces with a single method I would definitely still use the first approach. Here is the implementation of this approach for your interface:

```
public interface ISampleInterface
{
    void Run();
}

public class SampleClass : ISampleInterface
{
    public Action Run { get; set; }
    void ISampleInterface.Run()
    {
        this.Run();
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{    
    public void ActionRunner(ISampleInterface param)
    {
        param.Run();
    }
    public void someFumction()
    {
        ActionRunner(new SampleClass
        {
            Run = () =>
            {
                // Code goes here 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This Example Here im using Dependency Injection as well.

```
    public interface ISampleInterface
{
    void Run();
}

public class SampleClass : ISampleInterface
{
    public void Run()
    {
        // your business Logic Here.
    }
}

public class Test
{
    private ISampleInterface _sampleinterface;

    public Test(ISampleInterface sampleinterface)
    {
        _sampleinterface = sampleinterface;
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        _sampleinterface.Run();
    }
}
```